# in python, i have an int and want to substract it from a list

Tags: python, python-2.x

In python: how do I divide an int received by a user from a list while every time it runs in the for loop I need to divide the value I received from the round before in the next round?

This is my code:

```
a = input('price: ')
b = input('cash paid: ')
coin_bills = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.5]
if b >= a:
    for i in coin_bills:
        hef = b - a
        print (hef / i), '*', i
else:
    print 'pay up!'
```

Example: `a=370 b=500 ---> b-a=130`
Now in the loop I will receive (when i=100) 1, and (when i=50) I will receive 2 but I want in the second round (when i=50) to divide 30 (`130[=b-a]- 100[=answer of round 1*i]`) by 50.
What do I need to change in the code?
Thanks!

Comment: Why is everyone voting to close? OP has provided example input/output, and explained what's wrong with it, and has provided his code.

Comment: Sample input / output isn't very concise. I don't understand what exactly is being calculated. OP, are you calculating what currency to return as change?

Comment: its a cashier program. the cashier enters the price and the amount paid, then the program tells him how much change he needs to give back to the customer.

Comment: @user2751595 maybe you should explain that in the question to made it more clear

Answer (score 2):

You just need to subtract the amount of change you give back at each step from the total amount of change you're returning. It's much easier to see if you change your variable names to something meaningful:

```
price= int(raw_input('price: ')) # Use int(raw_input()) for safety.
paid= int(raw_input('cash paid: '))
coin_bills=[100,50,20,10,5,1,0.5]
if paid >= price:
    change = paid - price
    for i in coin_bills:
        # Use // to force integer division - not needed in Py2, but good practice
        # This means you can't give change in a size less than the smallest coin!
        print (change // i),'*',i
        change -= (change // i) * i # Subtract what you returned from the total change.
else:
    print 'pay up!'
```

You could also clear up the output a bit by only printing the coins/bills that you actually return. Then the inner loop might look something like this:

```
for i in coin_bills:
    coins_or_bills_returned = change // i
    if coins_or_bills_returned: # Only print if there's something worth saying.
        print coins_or_bills_returned,'*',i
        change -= coins_or_bills_returned * i
```

Comment: This is a good answer. A few brief suggestions though: For Python 2, you either want to use `int(raw_input())` or the regular `input()` function without `int` (as the questioner did). If you want to look towards Python 3 compatibility, you probably want to use "floor division" in the loop: `change // i`.

Comment: @Blckknght I was just in the middle of changing the division signs for  clarity :-) I didn't think it was worth getting into a whole Python2/3 thing though; I only wrapped the `input` function to quietly make myself happier. I've cleaned it up a bit now.

Comment: "Floor division" isn't necessarily appropriate for the lowest denomination, though, since if there is a fractional amount of that denomination, you'll want to calculate that fraction.

Comment: @MarkR.Wilkins Why would I want to do that? Am I going to cut up my coins into abritrarily-small pieces? The asker's code doesn't seem like it's intended to use non-integer division anywhere...

Comment: You're constrained to use float division if you're dividing by 0.5, which is in his list of denominations.  You could use // and check whether the remainder is equal to 0, I guess, but floating-point roundoff error could make that problematic, so you'd want to use an epsilon and it gets to be a hassle.

Comment: @MarkR.Wilkins Sorry, I should have said non-floor division. If a customer writes a check for $5.005 for a $5 item, I'm not going to cut a penny in half as change; I'm going to assume he's trying to give me a really worthless tip. But I do see your point; technically this is different from the way the asker's code would handle such a situation, and that's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm assuming that you're trying to calculate change for a transaction using a number of types of bills.

The problem is that you need to keep a running tally of how much change you have left to pay out.  I used `num_curr_bill` to calculate how many of the current bill type you're paying out, and your `hef` I changed to `remaining_change` (so it would mean something to me) for the remaining change to pay.

```
a= input('price: ')
b= input('cash paid: ')
coin_bills=[100,50,20,10,5,1,0.5]

if b>=a:
    # Calculate total change to pay out, ONCE (so not in the loop)
    remaining_change = b-a

    for i in coin_bills:
        # Find the number of the current bill to pay out
        num_curr_bill = remaining_change/i

        # Subtract how much you paid out with the current bill from the remaining change
        remaining_change -= num_curr_bill * i

        # Print the result for the current bill.
        print num_curr_bill,'*',i
else:
    print 'pay up!'
```

So, for a price of 120 and cash paid 175, the output is:

```
price: 120
cash paid: 175
0 * 100
1 * 50
0 * 20
0 * 10
1 * 5
0 * 1
0.0 * 0.5
```

One bill for 50 and one for 5 add up to 55, the correct change.

Edit:  I'd go more sparingly on the comments in my own code, but I added them here for explanation so that you could more clearly see what my thought process was.

Edit 2:  I would consider removing the 0.5 in coin_bills and replacing 1 with 1.0, since any fractional amounts will wind up being fractions of 0.5 anyway.